# Yii2 DB Expression in ActiveQuery::andFilterWhere()

Tags: yii2

I have the following code which filters an ActiveQuery

```
// Start date condition
if ($this->start_date) {
    $query->andWhere('event_datetime >= :start_date', [
        'start_date' => $this->start_date,
    ]);
}

// End date condition
if ($this->end_date) {
    $query->andWhere('event_datetime < :end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY', [
        'end_date' => $this->end_date,
    ]);
}
```

where `$this->start_date` and `$this->end_date` are either `null`, `''`, or in the form `Y-m-d`, and `event_datetime` is an indexed `DATETIME` column

Provided that both date properties are `true`, this code produces the following SQL

```
WHERE event_datetime >= :start_date
  AND event_datetime < :end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

---

I can rewrite the start date condition as

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'event_datetime', $this->start_date);
```

Is it possible to rewrite the end date condition simlarly, perhaps using some kind of DB expression?

I'd rather keep the `'+ INTERVAL 1 DAY'` in SQL, if possible, and still be able to use an index on `event_datetime`

Comment: It's not possible. "filterWhere" methods ignore conditions where operand is empty. But your operand would never be empty if you add '+ INTERVAL 1 DAY' string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from your date is `null` or empty `''`, what I am trying to understand is that why are you not using `DateTime` class along with `DateInterval` to set the `$this->end_date` to the final date after adding the interval and compare it with your column `event_datetime` rather than getting confused about it.

```
$endDate = $this->end_date;

if ($this->end_date !==null && $this->end_date!=='') {
    $endDateObj = new \DateTime($this->end_date);
    $endDateObj->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
    $endDate = $endDateObj->format('Y-m-d');
}

$query->andFilterWhere(['<','event_datetime', $endDate]);
```

**BUT**, if you are still feeling sleepy head and dizzy and not feel like doing it in PHP for having personal reasons like increase in Blood Pressure, insomnia or your body start shivering thinking of PHP **:P** you can do it via [`\yii\db\Expression()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression) in the following way which will produce the query like `WHERE created_at < '2019-10-22' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`, i have tested it but not sure how accurate it will be so test it before you go for it.

```
$query->andFilterWhere(
    [
        '<',
        'event_datetime',
        new \yii\db\Expression("'$this->end_date' + INTERVAL 1 DAY")
    ]
);
```

#### EDIT

You have to check manually the value for `null` and empty before you use any of the methods above and that is the only way you can do that. A little addition is needed to control the blank or null value which wont be controlled in the `Expression` automatically and will give incorrect results so change to the following

```
$expression = null;
$isValidDate = null !== $this->end_date && $this->end_date !== '';

//prepare the expression if the date is not null or empty
if ($isValidDate) {

    $expression = new Expression(
        ":my_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY",
        [
            ':my_date' => $this->end_date,
        ]
    );
}

$query->andFilterWhere(
    [
        '>',
        'end_date',
        $expression,
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your top suggestion is fine, but wrapping it in a null check defeats the point of using the filterWhere, and ends up being heavier, and less readable, than the original… Your second suggestion is ripe for SQL injection (the constructor for Expression actually lets you bind in values with a second parameter), and doesn't handle the empty cases properly. I may just leave the original code

Comment: OOps about the SQL injection, the intention was to provide the approach, will update that too, and the check for `null` should be for the calculation of the interval with `DateTime` class only and not the `andFilterWhere`, i some how ended up adding that line inside the check, also we need to initialize the `$endDate = $this->end_date` before the check and after the check we should just `$query->andFilterWhere(['<','event_datetime', $endDate]);` @Arth

Answer (score 0):

*A supplemental answer to @Muhammad's, and supported by @Michal's comment on my original question*

The `ActiveQuery::andFilterWhere()` function ignores empty operands, so we can set up our expression or manipulated value, `$endDate`, to remain empty when the original value is empty

**either** using PHP's DateTime

```
$endDate = $this->end_date ? 
    (new DateTime($this->end_date . ' + 1 day'))->format('Y-m-d') :
    null;
```

**or** using Yii's Expression

```
$endDate = $this->end_date ? 
    new Expression(':end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY', ['end_date' => $this->end_date]) :
    null;
```

Then `ActiveQuery::andFilterWhere()` can be used as follows

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['<','end_date', $endDate]);
```